# BeautifulSoup - how to extract text without opening tag and before <br> tag?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm new to python and beautifulsoup and spent quite a few hours trying to figure this one out.
I want to extract three particular text extracts within a `<div>` that has no class.
The first text extract I want is within an `<a>` tag which is within an `<h4>` tag. This I managed to extract it.
The second text extract immediately follows the closing h4 tag `</h4>` and is followed by a `<br>` tag.
The third text extract immediately follows the `<br>` tag after the second text extract and is also followed by a `<br>` tag.

Here the html extract I work with:

```
<div>
    <h4 class="actorboxLink">
    <a href="/a-decheterie-de-bagnols-2689">Decheterie de Bagnols</a>
    </h4>
    Route des 4 Vents<br>
    63810 Bagnols<br>
</div>
```

I want to extract:

Decheterie de Bagnols < That works

Route des 4 Vents < Doesn't work

63810 Bagnols < Doesn't work

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
name = soup.findAll("h4", class_="actorboxLink")

for a_tag in name:
    print a_tag.text.strip()
```

I need something like "soup.findAll(*all text after `</h4>`*)"

I played with using .next_sibling but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas? Thanks

UPDATE:
I tried this:

```
for a_tag in classActorboxLink:
    print a_tag.find_all_next(string=True, limit=5)
```

which gives me:
[u'\n', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tDecheterie\xa0de\xa0Bagnols\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n', u'\r\n\t\t\t\tRoute\xa0des\xa04\xa0Vents', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t63810 Bagnols']

It's a start but I need to relove all the whitespaces and unecessary characters. I tried using `.strip()`,`.strings` and `.stripped_strings` but it doesn't work. Examples:

```
for a_tag in classActorboxLink.strings

for a_tag in classActorboxLink.stripped_strings

print a_tag.find_all_next(string=True, limit=5).strip()
```

For all three I get:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'strings/stripped_strings/strip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `h4` element and use [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
h4s = soup.find_all("h4", class_="actorboxLink")
for h4 in h4s:
    for text in h4.find_next_siblings(text=True):
        print(text.strip())
```

Comment: That gave me this error: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_next_siblings'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need each of the 3 elements you are looking for in different variables you could just use the `get_text()` function on the `<div>` to get them all in one string.  If there are other `div` tags but they all have classes you can find all the `<div>` with `class=false`.  If you can't isolate the `<div>` that you are interested in then this solution won't work for you.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for name in soup.find_all("div", class=false)
     print name.get_text().strip()
```

BTW this is python 3 & bs4

Comment: Good suggestion but yep I can't isolate the <div> I'm interested in...too many of them